# Adjusting Font sizes in Group plots using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Using this code to plot multiple charts I can't seem to adjust the font size on the titles, I need them bigger... The font code in the code does bold the axis labels but does not seem to either bold the title nor change the size of the axis labels nor the bold or change the title.. so I guess it is getting overridden by something in the layout?

```
area_tabs=['1']
nrows = int(math.ceil(len(area_tabs) / 2.))
figlen=nrows*7 #adjust the figure size height to be sized to the number of rows
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 25,figlen
font = {'family' : 'normal',
    'weight' : 'bold',
    'size'   : 30}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, 2, sharey=False)
for ax, area_tabs in zip(axs.flat, area_tabs):
    ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='both')
    actdf, aname = get_data(area_tabs)
    fullyrs,lastq,fcast_yr,projections,yrahead,aname,actdf,merged2,mergederrs,montdist,ols_test,    mergedfcst,curr_month=do_projections(actdf,aname)
    lastyrtot=str(merged2['Units'][-2:-1].iloc[0])
    mergederrs[['fcast','Units']].tail(12).plot(ax=ax, title='''Area: {0} Forecast for 2014 {1:,} vs. Actual 2013 of {2:,}
{3} sales year to date, compared to forecast of {4} a cumulative error of {5}%'''.format(unicode(aname),int(mergederrs['fcastcum'][-1:].iloc[0]),
int(float((lastyrtot))),int(mergederrs['unitscum'][curr_month]),int(mergederrs['fcastcum'][curr_month]),(mergederrs['cumerrpercent'][curr_month])))
```

Yields something like this:
[image: Statewide Chart]

Comment: `ax.set_title('title text', size=100)`

Comment: The title is set dynamically in the last line via .plot(ax=ax...... so how?

Comment: Amending the last line as [curr_month]), size=100)) does nothing

Comment: hey man -- just a tip: your examples should be reproducible. as it stands, no one but you can run this code with all the undefined variables and functions.

Comment: Sorry about that, I usually try to do that! the complexity here was part of the issue.. (not a good excuse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way:

`ax.set_title(ax.get_title(), fontsize=20)`

Comment: That does it! when I add it after the last current line, after the plot is created.